# How does Magento 2 sku generated automatically?

Tags: magento2.3, sku, di, data-provider, modifier

I want to know how does Magento 2 sku generated automaticlly.

I wonder when I type product name while creating new product in admin then its sku is automatically typed in sku field.

I researched much and found that there is a functionality called "**Modifier**" in Magento 2 in which product edit section can be added/edited with some extra features.

Also found that there are two methods in modifier class, "**modifyMeta**" & "**modifyData**" that can be used to add/edit product edit fields.

But I am totally dumb that how sku is generated automatically and which file I will have to override to make sku in our own way.

Right now sku is generated based on product name but I want to make it something like **somedigits+autogenerated_sku** eg: **00000testsku**.

Is there anyone who can hints at it and give some light on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sku generation has settings: **Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog**
[image]

Change **Mask for SKU** to **somedigits_{{name}}**

**[Update]**

SKU js component: **Magento_Catalog/js/components/import-handler**

***Location***: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/js/components/import-handler.js

Overwrite this component what you want here.

Comment: I know it but it will not work as expected that I asked in my question.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: Thanks mate!!!!